# Android - How can i make results from recognizer to determine 1st and 2nd word separately?

Tags: java, android

Here is my code:

```
if (results.contains("search"))
{
    int firstSpaceEntry = 0, lastIndex = 0, index = 0;
    String tempString = "";
     
    for (String sExtract : myResults)
    {
        lastIndex = sExtract.length();
        firstSpaceEntry = sExtract.indexOf(" ");
         
        if (firstSpaceEntry < lastIndex)
        {
            tempString = sExtract.substring(firstSpaceEntry, lastIndex);
            myExtract.set(index, tempString);
             
            System.err.println(" index = "+index+" value = "+tempString);
             
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is that when i say 'search' it works. BUT when i say search + other words it does not work. =/

Comment: Off topic, but shouldn't it be like: lastIndex = sExtract.length() - 1;

Answer (score 1):

First -- you can omit the "lastIndex" entirely. indexOf will return -1 if not found, and substring will continue through the end of the line if the second parameter is omitted.

Second -- while fuzzy on the details (do you mean that the results variable works when "search" but fails when "search stuff"?), you may also try using indexOf instead of contains.

Third -- is "results" a list or a string? I'm assuming the latter in the code below, but if it's the former, then that would explain why "contains" only works when you use "search" with no additional words. If that's the case, you'll need to loop through the results array, and test each value individually whether it contains / startsWith / etc "search".

```
if (results.indexOf("search") > -1)
{
    int firstSpaceEntry = 0, lastIndex = 0, index = 0;
    String tempString = "";
     
    for (String sExtract : myResults)
    {
        firstSpaceEntry = sExtract.indexOf(" ");
         
        if (firstSpaceEntry > -1)
        {
            tempString = sExtract.substring(firstSpaceEntry);
            myExtract.set(index, tempString);
             
            System.err.println(" index = "+index+" value = "+tempString);
             
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```